# How to iterate over enumerators of an enum class?

Tags: c++, initialization, unordered-set, enum-class

Is there a way to initialize a container (e.g. `std::unordered_set<char>`) with the *enumerators* of an `enum class`?

I have this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>


class Foo
{
public:

    inline static const std::unordered_set<char> chars_for_drawing { '/', '\\', '|', '-' };
};


int main( )
{
    for ( const char ch : Foo::chars_for_drawing )
    {
        std::cout << ch << ' ';
    }
}
```

But I want the `chars_for_drawing` set to be initialized with the enumerators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>


class Foo
{
public:
    enum class AllowedChars : char
    {
        ForwardSlash = '/',
        BackSlash = '\\',
        VerticalSlash = '|',
        Dash = '-'
    };

    // inline static const std::unordered_set<char> chars_for_drawing { '/', '\\', '|', '-' }; // not like this

    inline static const std::unordered_set<char> chars_for_drawing {
                                                                     static_cast<char>( AllowedChars::ForwardSlash ),
                                                                     static_cast<char>( AllowedChars::BackSlash ),
                                                                     static_cast<char>( AllowedChars::VerticalSlash ),
                                                                     static_cast<char>( AllowedChars::Dash )
                                                                    };
};


int main( )
{
    for ( const char ch : Foo::chars_for_drawing )
    {
        std::cout << ch << ' ';
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the second approach is a bit messy. Is there way to iterate over the enumerators and assign them to the `unordered_set`? Maybe by using a lambda?

Comment: enums have a huge gap between how we would like them to be and what they really are ;). Would it be an option to have consecutive values for the enumerators (and supply the mapping to chars differently) ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't get it. Could you give more explanations?

Comment: "Is there way to iterate" No.

Comment: `enum class Foo { bar, quux, baz };` then `vector<Foo> FooX{Foo::bar, Foo::quux, Foo::baz};`.  Now you can iterate using FooX of the Foo enumdefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no straightforward way. Something one often forgets: The range of the enums values is determined by its underlying type. The enumerators are just some named constants. Your enum:

```
enum class AllowedChars : char
{
    ForwardSlash = '/',
    BackSlash = '\\',
    VerticalSlash = '|',
    Dash = '-'
};
```

helps for iterating as much as a

```
struct {
    char value;
    static const char ForwardSlash = '/';
    static const char BackSlash = '\\';
    static const char VerticalSlash = '|';
    static const char Dash = '-';
};
```

does: Not at all.

Things are different when the enumerators have consecutive values and a hack that is used sometimes is to use a special enumerator to denote the "size":

```
enum class AllowedChars : char
{
    ForwardSlash,
    BackSlash,
    VerticalSlash,
    Dash,
    SIZE
};

int main() {
    for (int i=0;i< static_cast<int>(AllowedChars::SIZE); ++i){
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

That alone is a little silly, because the mapping to the actual characters is lost. However, it can be supplied by an array:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class AllowedCharNames : char
{
    ForwardSlash,
    BackSlash,
    VerticalSlash,
    Dash,
    SIZE
};

char AllowedChars[] = {'/','\\','|','-'};

int main() {
    std::cout << AllowedChars[static_cast<size_t>(AllowedCharNames::Dash)];
    for (int i=0;i< static_cast<int>(AllowedCharNames::SIZE); ++i){
        std::cout << AllowedChars[i];
    }
}
```

TL;DR Reconsider if an enum is the right tool for the job. Enums are often overestimated for what they can really do. Sometimes not an enum is the better alternative.

Comment: What about the visibility of my enum class? Should I make it private since no other class is going to access it?

Comment: @digito_evo if nobody is going to access it, why use an enum in the first place? Sorry, I dont understand the question (what class?)

Comment: I mean `AllowedChars`

Comment: @digito_evo if you used the enum because you thought it help to iterate then don't use it, it doesn't help. If the enum is there for other reasons then thats kind of orthogonal. Making stuff private that doesn't need to be public is good practice, though Im not really sure what you mean because they arent member of some class

Comment: The enum class is a member of `Foo`.

Comment: @digito_evo ups sorry ;) didnt pay attention.

Comment: I updated theb question. Now I decided to switch to enum because it has the implicit conversion and I don't want to have lots of `static_cast`s all over the code. Now the `contains` function is giving an error.

Comment: @digito_evo please do not change the question to ask for something else. If you have a different question you can open another question

Comment: Ok. But it's just a minor change. Also, the `contains` function requires a `static_cast<Foo::AllowedChars>`. I think I figured out how to do it.

Comment: @digito_evo its not a minor change. My answer is for using `enum class` and it is not about the error you get with `contains`. It is about the question you did ask initially

Comment: Ok. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the `enum` and `enum class` do not provide the kind of functionality you want.

You can implement that functionality yourself.  There is considerable boilerplate, but it may be worth it since it will make the callsite considerably easier to use.

Depending on the enumeration definitions of an `enum` or `enum class`, the implementation routines can accommodate sequences with gaps.

Here is an example, with a simple `enum class`, that has gaps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::logic_error;
using std::ostream;
using std::underlying_type_t;

namespace {


enum class Lorem {
    ipsum = 10, dolor = 20, sit = 30, amet = 100, consectetur = 105, adipiscing = 111
};

auto Lorem_first() -> Lorem { return Lorem::ipsum; }
auto Lorem_last() -> Lorem { return Lorem::adipiscing; }

auto operator<<(ostream& out, Lorem e) -> ostream& {
    switch(e) {
#define CASE(x) case Lorem::x: return out << #x
        CASE(ipsum);
        CASE(dolor);
        CASE(sit);
        CASE(amet);
        CASE(consectetur);
        CASE(adipiscing);
#undef CASE
    }

    throw logic_error("operator<< unknown Lorem");
}

auto operator+(Lorem e) -> underlying_type_t<decltype(e)> {
    return static_cast<underlying_type_t<decltype(e)>>(e);
}

auto operator++(Lorem& e) -> Lorem& {
    if (e == Lorem_last()) throw logic_error("operator++(Lorem&)");
    switch(e) {
#define CASE(x, y) case Lorem::x: e = Lorem::y; break
        CASE(ipsum, dolor);
        CASE(dolor, sit);
        CASE(sit, amet);
        CASE(amet, consectetur);
        CASE(consectetur, adipiscing);
#undef CASE
        case Lorem::adipiscing: break;
    }
    return e;
}

class Lorem_Range {
    bool done = false;
    Lorem iter = Lorem_first();

public:
    auto begin() const -> Lorem_Range const& { return *this; }
    auto end() const -> Lorem_Range const& { return *this; }
    auto operator*() const -> Lorem { return iter; }
    bool operator!=(Lorem_Range const&) const { return !done; }
    void operator++() {
        if (done) {
            throw logic_error("Lorem_Range::operator++");
        }

        if (iter == Lorem_last()) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    for (auto e : Lorem_Range()) {
        cout << +e << ", " << e << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thats nice, but OPs case is all about the enumerators not being consecutive